# Performing Click on Menu didn't work well on IE 10 using Selenim2Library and RobotFramework

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webbrowser-control, robotframework

I am testing a web application that contains menu. 
With IE8, there is no issue with clicking on menu using code below

```
Click Link  xpath=//div/ul/li[2]/a[contains(text(),'mon organisation')]         

Click Link  xpath=//div/ul/li[2]/ul/li[1]/a[contains(text(),'sites')]
```

But with IE10, I have issues with this code. Click link doesn't work very well.

I have used also `Click Element` and `Press Key` Keywords but it doesn't work.

What's the solution of such problem? There is any alternative to solve this problem?

Comment: This question is way too broad. It could be any number of things -- maybe you have javascript that deletes DOM elements, maybe they are in an iframe, maybe they are not visible, etc.

Comment: Anyway thanks for your response. I did have iframe in my web application and every time when i need to locate an object in this iframe i use the keyword select frame .I 'm asking this question cause i didn't face this problem before using Selenium-Webdriver with Junit Framework.

Answer (score 0):

First I would say do not use xpaths, seriously dont... They are not only slow but can differ between builds and can differ between browsers, not good for writing stable tests.

I would recommend using jquery selectors such as:

```
Click Element    jquery=a:contains("mon organisation")
Click Element    jquery=a:contains("sites")
```

This method looks better, is more reliable and so much faster!

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your response. In fact, i did use jquery to identify objects but i still face the same problem with menu. This problem is related only to newest version of browsers. For example, with IE8, i didn't face the problem of clicking on link element but unfortunately with IE10 i did. In general, there is a lot of problems with click on element using IE10. If you have any idea about this issue please inform me cause i didn't find any solution and i have to automate robust test on IE10 browser and newest version of Firefox (FF ESR 24.8.1)

Comment: To help much further I would need to see the website code... It can be hard to help automate without seeing the HTML/css/JavaScript that relates to the problem.